# Looking for a 24vac switch from 3v inputs

Tags: relay, multiplexer

I'm really new to building electronics, so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm looking to be able to supply 24vac (~.5A) to one of 16 outputs using 4 3.3v, 50mA inputs.
(Edited)  The 4 3.3v inputs are from a microcontroller, that I want to use to select one of the 16 outputs (traditional multiplexer problem).  I was hoping that there is some sort of multiplexer that I could hook up down stream from a relay in order to supply the power with few components.  So I'm looking to find/build a multiplexer circuit that takes 4 on/off low power inputs and the "data" line is 24vac.  My alternative is using a multiplexer and relays/TRIACs.

I've seen posts where people use TRIACs/relays directly for this, or use a multiplexer to run a number of TRIACs and relays.  I also saw someone talking about using MOSFETs...  I'd rather use less components if possible.

EDIT:

After doing some more research, I think I need a 1:16 analog switch.  I think I need something with an optocoupler or something that will protect my circuit board from the 24vac that will be switched.  I looked at the DG406DJZ and 
NTE4051B... but I really can't tell if they meet my needs.

EDIT:

Well, I ended up buying this: DG406DJ-E3 : http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/249648/VISHAY/DG406DJ-E3/219/1/DG406DJ-E3.html.  The 5 data lines will be 3.3V, 50mA.  The analog connect will be 24vac at .5A or so, to be switched to one of 16 outputs.  I think this is an isolated circuit so I shouldn't have to worry about ruining my board in cases of failure.  Is this really going to work like I think it will?  Will my microcontroller be protected with this setup?  Is there something else I should be considering?  This seems like a simple design based on some of the others I have seen.

Answer (score -1):

A door bell transformer should fit that very well. Do you need to do it the other way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I probably should be more specific in my question.